# Shape width estimation from raster

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, opencv

I want to estimate the measurements of a shape present in a given raster image and I want to know what is the proper way of handling the measurement dependence on the projection.

More specifically, I want to measure the widths of every road present in binary image, obtained from the segmentation of satellite images. The region I am studying is New York city. The imagery is divided into tiles, following the OSM slippy tilemap convention.

[image: This is an example of the image I use.]

Considering the four corners of the image, I tried to compare the distances in the vertical direction and in the horizontal directions and I obtained (as expected) different results (76m, 16m).

I can already calculate the road widths in pixels and I can even convert them to real distances (haversine), but I am assuming the distances are not dependent on the orientation of the roads, i.e., a road in the vertical direction of my image that is 6 pixels wide have the same real width (in meters) of a 6-pixel-wide road in the horizontal direction.

To summarize, I have a raster image and I want to properly estimate the real width of the shapes. Any ideas?

Comment: @MrXsquared I program in Python, with opencv for image processing